# Activating and Training a 2 layer deep network

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, deep-learning

Summary: deep-learning networks return undefined for output when activated

I've been working with synaptic.js to make neural-networks in the browser for a while and I've decided I want to implemented deep-learning for a project I'm working on ( connecting an lstm to a classifier ).

I've successfully created both networks and can project the output of the lstm to the input of the classifier, but I get issues when I try to activate and perhaps train it.

First, it trains very quickly ( but, granted, I'm training it with 2 simple, inputs so that might not be an issue ). But it trains with out error. I train it with a single input as it has one input neuron and then 5 outputs for each class.

Now when I activate it, I don't get an error, but I get that all of the outputs are undefined: `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]` with an activation of `[0]`, which was explicitly trained.

I'd greatly appreciate any help in getting this small deep network working. Each network works individually, but I believe there is an issue in training both together. If I were to train them separately-- what would be the ideal-output for the lstm and the input for the classifier I would train them separately with?

[Here is synaptic: https://github.com/cazala/synaptic](https://github.com/cazala/synaptic)

[Here is my implementation](http://pastebin.com/XSjJQWT5)( Synaptic is the majority at the top and my code is at the bottom. It can be run in the browser console. Activating it with `deep.activate([0]);` ) Below is just my implementation-- the full with synaptic.js is in the link.

```
function flstm(input, memoryBlocks, output, hidden, classes){
    var layerCount=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        previous=null,
        hiddenLayers=[],
        inputLSTM=new Layer(input),
        outputLSTM=new Layer(output),
        inputClassifier=new Layer(output),
        hiddenLayer=new Layer(hidden),
        outputClassifier=new Layer(classes);

        for(var layer in layerCount){
            var size=layerCount[layer], memoryCell=new Layer(size);
            var inputGate=new Layer(size).set({
                    bias:1
            });
            var forgetGate = new Layer(size).set({
                bias:1
            });
            var outputGate=new Layer(size).set({
                bias:1
            });
            hiddenLayers.push(inputGate);
            hiddenLayers.push(forgetGate);
            hiddenLayers.push(memoryCell);
            hiddenLayers.push(outputGate);

            //lstm's inputLayer connections
            var input=inputLSTM.project(memoryCell);
            inputLSTM.project(inputGate);
            inputLSTM.project(forgetGate);
            inputLSTM.project(outputGate);

            //previous memory-block's connections
            if(previous!==null){
                var cell=previous.project(memoryCell);
                previous.project(inputGate);
                previous.project(forgetGate);
                previous.project(outputGate);
            }

            //memory-cell's connections
            var output=memoryCell.project(outputLSTM);

            //recurrent-connection
            var self=memoryCell.project(memoryCell);
            //gates ( bill? )
            inputGate.gate(input, Layer.gateType.INPUT);
            forgetGate.gate(self, Layer.gateType.ONE_TO_ONE);
            outputGate.gate(output, Layer.gateType.OUTPUT);
            if(previous!==null) inputGate.gate(cell, Layer.gateType.INPUT);
            //peepholes ( call Tom )
            memoryCell.project(inputGate);
            memoryCell.project(forgetGate);
            memoryCell.project(outputGate);
            previous=memoryCell;
        }

        //lstm's input to lstm's output direct connection
        inputLSTM.project(outputLSTM);

        //classifier's connections
        inputClassifier.project(hiddenLayer);
        hiddenLayer.project(outputClassifier);

        //deep connections
        outputLSTM.project(inputClassifier);

        this.set({
            input: inputLSTM,
            hidden: hiddenLayers.concat([hiddenLayer]),
            output: outputClassifier
        });
}
flstm.prototype=new Network();
flstm.prototype.constructor=flstm;

var sa=new flstm(1, 16, 1, 8, 5);
var trainer=new Trainer(sa);
trainer.workerTrain([{input:[0], output:[1,0,0,0,0]}, {input:[1], output:[0,1,0,0,0]}], alert('done'));
```

Thank you in Advance

Comment: First of all, 1 year later, you can just create an LSTM quite easily. Just use the built in `Architect.LSTM`, take a look here https://github.com/cazala/synaptic/wiki/Architect#lstm

Comment: @ThomasW You could do that back then too. I was trying to create a deep network of a feed forward network connected to an lstm. Every time I tried to train it, I would get the same result for every query and I tried very large amounts of training data.